# SQL (postgres) - Recursive view for all parents of a child

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, recursive-query

**Solved** below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71149082/8082262

I have two tables: `community2collection(collection_id,community_id)` and `community2community(child_comm_id,parent_comm_id)`.

I'm trying to create a recursive view that for any given collection (`collection_id`) will return a list of the direct community parent (community_id), as well as any ancestor of the direct community (so recursively going through `community2community`.

I had

```
CREATE VIEW hierarchical_comcoltree
AS
    WITH RECURSIVE comcoltree AS
      (SELECT collection_id,
              community_id AS any_community_id
       FROM community2collection
       UNION ALL SELECT com2col.collection_id,
                        com2com.parent_comm_id AS any_community_id
       FROM community2collection com2col
       INNER JOIN community2community com2com
       ON com2com.child_comm_id = com2col.community_id)
    SELECT * FROM comcoltree;
```

But this only retrieves the direct community, as well as its first parent, but not further ancestors, with query

```
SELECT collection_id,
       any_community_id
FROM hierarchical_comcoltree
WHERE collection_id = '13081d45-dcdc-4e4d-94a5-33056c9f0c49'
ORDER BY collection_id ASC;
```

Any help would be appreciated, tried a few variations (as well as with a function), but haven't found one that works yet...

**Test data**

`community2collection`

| collection_id | community_id |
| --- | --- |
| 13081d45-dcdc-4e4d-94a5-33056c9f0c49 | 17475c16-a03e-4f5f-8928-bef6a4813978 |
| cbc98392-ba86-4ed3-b477-5a4a7652f3f0 | 88aa4abd-d024-47d2-a1a4-bdb3d744dd24 |

`community2community`

| child_comm_id | parent_comm_id |
| --- | --- |
| 17475c16-a03e-4f5f-8928-bef6a4813978 | ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a |
| ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a | 05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f |
| 88aa4abd-d024-47d2-a1a4-bdb3d744dd24 | 726a8531-4441-4feb-a8fc-b089445bc39e |
| 726a8531-4441-4feb-a8fc-b089445bc39e | ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a |
| ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a | 05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f |

- Expected results view for first collection `'13081d45-dcdc-4e4d-94a5-33056c9f0c49'`

=> `'17475c16-a03e-4f5f-8928-bef6a4813978'`, `'ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a'` and `'05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f'`

=> Missing last one with current solution

- Expected results view for second collection `'cbc98392-ba86-4ed3-b477-5a4a7652f3f0'`

=> `'88aa4abd-d024-47d2-a1a4-bdb3d744dd24'`, `'726a8531-4441-4feb-a8fc-b089445bc39e'`, `'ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a'` and `'05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f'`

=> Missing last two ones with current solution

Testing with:

```
WITH RECURSIVE comcoltree AS
  (SELECT collection_id,
          community_id AS any_community_id
   FROM community2collection
   UNION ALL SELECT com2col.collection_id,
                    com2com.parent_comm_id AS any_community_id
   FROM community2collection com2col
   INNER JOIN community2community com2com ON com2com.child_comm_id = com2col.community_id)
SELECT collection_id,
       any_community_id
FROM comcoltree
WHERE any_community_id = 'cbc98392-ba86-4ed3-b477-5a4a7652f3f0'
ORDER BY collection_id ASC;
```

Comment: Can you give us some test data? Seems like you need to be joining with `parent_comm_id` rather than `child_comm_id`

Comment: @JSpratt : Added test data, switching around `parent_comm_id` and `child_comm_id` doesn't  fix it... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're not joining against the recursive CTE (`comcoltree`). Therefore, you're never adding anything to the result set with the `UNION`. This is the best I have with the provided information:

```
WITH RECURSIVE comcoltree AS
(
    SELECT collection_id
         , community_id     AS any_community_id
      FROM community2collection
     WHERE collection_id = 'cbc98392-ba86-4ed3-b477-5a4a7652f3f0'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT prev.collection_id
         , next.parent_comm_id AS any_community_id
      FROM comcoltree prev
      JOIN community2community next ON prev.any_community_id = next.child_comm_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
       collection_id
     , any_community_id
  FROM comcoltree
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1f852b2f24806abdd60dc8269ccae24f) is a DBFiddle to show it working. I threw the distinct in there because there were duplicates in the result set but I think that's due to having a duplicate in the sample data.

`ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a   05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f`

Comment: This seems to indeed work for my examples, thank you very much! :D
Time to test it on some more examples by putting it in a VIEW.
The duplicate in test data is my bad, shouldn't be any duplicates in the actual DB, so I think I can do without the distinct, but thanks for including it ^^

So if I understand correctly, the instead of recursively joining the com2col and com2com, you join the recursive tree itself with com2com?

Comment: That's correct, your entry point is a collection. After grabbing its community, you're only recursing com2com to find the ancestor communities. If you remove the where clause from the base query, you'll get the ancestry for every collection... might be useful for your view.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, thank you again, it looks to be working as a VIEW as well.
New to recursive queries. All examples I found were for 1 child-parent relationship table, just com2com for example, so the added collection link made those hard to apply to mine.

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy! Recursive queries aren't the easiest thing to learn but once you practice with it a bit you'll get the hang of it.